# Can't access local databases after Domino Server install

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I've installed Domino Server on my local machine today, which is working flawlessly by the way. But now, when I try to open an application that is on local, I get forbidden access even though I could open it before and in the ACL I have listed Anonymous with Designer rights.
I've searched and searched, and haven't come up with any solution. How can I fix this?

I hadn't noticed that my database files were signed with the Servers Id, so I signed the database with the Active Users Id and now everything works well.

Comment: What is the specific error message? Does your user id have rights to run XPages (see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21327868)?

Comment: wow that was fast :) I'm getting: Error 403
HTTP Web Server: You are forbidden to perform this operation

Comment: My user ID has Designer rights, but I'm opening the Xpage in the browser, which of course is trying to access it with Anonymous, which is listed in the ACL with Designer rights (just to make sure that's not the issue)

Comment: Your userid needs sufficients rights on the server. Check my answer below. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID that was used to create or sign the XPage you are attempting to access may not have 
sufficient rights on the server.

Ensure that the XPage is signed by an ID that, depending on the level of access that you want this user to have, is listed in either the "Sign or run unrestricted methods and operations" or "Sign agents or XPages to run on behalf of the invoker" fields (Server Document --> Security tab).

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21327868 for more details.

Comment: but where can I find the security document for my localhost server?

Comment: In your servers Directory database (names.nsf ) in the Configuration - Servers - All Server Documents view

Comment: Ok I think i've spotted the issue, all the elements in the application have been signed with the Servers ID. Is there a way to Sign the whole database with my local ID? OK that did it! :)

Comment: I didn't notice that the Servers id had signed all the items in the database, which of course has no access on localhost. So I signed the database with the Active users ID and now everything's back to normal :) Thank you for helping me though!

Comment: Yes, so as stated: "The ID that was used to create or sign the XPage you are attempting to access may not have sufficient rights on the server." :-)

Comment: exactly, but that was strange to me because the database is created with the Id that has all the rights (i've used the same Id so far). Until I noticed you were right :)